# Java Problems getting font color from .xlsx cell

Tags: java, excel, colors, styles, cell

I have a xlsx file that looks like this:

[image: Excel]

By using Java, I want to retrieve the **font color** present on **every cell**. What I need is just the text and font color. Font **style** or **size** and **background color** are **not** necessary. Note that **A5** cell has **2 words with different color**, so I need to get 2 colors from a single cell.

I tried using **POI API** but I can't reach what I want. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\example.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                    System.out.println(
                            "<<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: " + ((XSSFFont) ((XSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle()).getFont())
                                    .getXSSFColor().getARGBHex());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                    break;
                default:
                }
            }
            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code is simple:

1. Get the excel file
2. Get the Sheet
3. Iterate over the cells
4. Print the cell content and try to get the color with [XSSFCellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html)

But the output is not what I was expecting:

```
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF000000
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FFFF0000
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF70AD47
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FFCE88D0
hello world         <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF000000
hello           <<<<<<<<<<< COLOR: FF000000
```

1. Cases 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 are **OK** because it shows **its actual color**.
2. Case 5 is **not OK** because if there are **2 or more words with different color**, it returns **000000**, aka **BLACK**.

What I need in this last case is to have something like this:

```
hello <<<<<<<COLOR: FFEBCB46  world <<<<<<<<<<COLOR: FF70AD47
```

But I dont know how to scan color for every words in a single cell.

How can I do that? Is it impossible or should I use another API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on StackOverflow in Spanish and there is an [answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/542672/java-problemas-para-obtener-color-de-fuente-en-celda-de-excel-xlsx/542713#542713):

Basically, there are 2 aproaches:

1. Get char style (char per char) of the entire cell

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < richTextString.length(); i++) {
   String nextColor = font.((XSSFColor) ((XSSFFont)cell.getRichStringCellValue().getFontAtIndex(i))
       .getXSSFColor()).getARGBHex();
   ```

   ...
2. Parse RichStringCellValue() string value, since it has xml-based information about the entire cell, where every main block represents word or words (in the correct order) that have the same style.